# Change displayable labels for a JSlider?

Tags: java, swing, division, jslider

I have a JSlider with a min of 0 and a max of 10,000. I have the major tick marks set at 1,000. If I were to paint the labels now they would show up as 0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, etc. What I would like to be shown would be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc. What would be a good way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [JSlider.setLabelTable(Dictionary)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#setLabelTable())

EDIT

Alternatively you can rely on predefined label UI and just change the label text:

```
    Enumeration e = jSlider.getLabelTable().keys();

    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        Integer i = (Integer) e.nextElement();
        JLabel label = (JLabel) jSlider.getLabelTable().get(i);
        label.setText(String.valueOf(i / 1000));          
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `JSlider.setLabelTable(Dictionary)` to set specific labels for the values you wish to render differently; e.g.

```
JSlider slider = ...

Dictionary dict = new Hashtable();
for (int i=0; i<=10000; i += 1000) {  
  dict.put(i, new JLabel(Integer.toString(i / 1000)));
}

slider.setLabelTable(dict);
```

(Edited based on previous comments.)

Comment: Dictionary is an abstract class, so you might want to use Hashtable instead.  You also need to get the number 10 in there.  your for loop doesnt allow for that.

Comment: Dictionary is abstract and cannot be instantied

Comment: rebuilding the label from scratch maybe a bad idea (using Java6 on windows the labels are broken)

Comment: How are they broken?  I'm using Alloy L&F on Windows and JLabels seem ok.  What would be the alternative to rebuilding the JLabel from scratch?

Comment: check my answer (I'm on windows 7 with jdk 1.6u14)