# How to set the labels (LabelTable) of an uicomponent slider (jslider)?

Tags: matlab, slider, label, jslider, uicomponents

I created a slider using `uicomponent` which can be found on [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14583-uicomponent-expands-uicontrol-to-all-java-classes)

```
handles.slid=uicomponent('style','slider',0,90,5);
handles.slid.MajorTickSpacing=10;
handles.slid.MinorTickSpacing=10;
handles.slid.Paintlabels=1;
handles.slid.PaintTicks=1;
```

The labels were initially set as **0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90**

Is it possible to set the labels as **a b c d e f g h i j**?

Comment: Its not an exact duplicate, but this questions might have part of what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697780/java-jslider-set-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use Java for that. The simplest way I can think of is to modify the existing LabelTable of the JSlider Java component you have already created. Try the following code:

```
labels = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};
lt =get(hu_slider, 'LabelTable');
for i=1:10
    key = java.lang.Integer(10*(i-1));
    val = lt.get(key);
    val.setText(labels{i});
    lt.put(key, val);
end
set(hu_slider, 'LabelTable', lt);
hu_slider.JavaComponent.updateUI;
```

It works with the assumption that you have 10 ticks, of course.